# Polling in React Typescript

Tags: typescript, polling

I'm trying to implement a polling function in React using typescript. The polling function needs to make a REST API call to read a record in DynamoDB and continue polling every 30s until the 'Status' field in the record is 'Success'.

Code I tried:

```
const poll = async function (fn: () => Promise<any>, fnCondition: (result: any) => boolean, ms: number): Promise<any> {
    let result = await fn();
    while (fnCondition(result)) {
      await wait(ms);
      result = await fn();
    }
    return result;
  };

const wait = async function (ms = 1000): Promise<void> {
    console.log('in wait function');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  };

function callPolling(resJson: any): any {
    try {
    response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(request_data),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  } catch (e: unknown) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  return response;
  }

const fetchRecord = callPolling(resJson);
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const validate = (result: { body: { Status: string } }) => result.body.Status === 'Success';
const responsePoll = await poll(fetchRecord, validate, 30000);
```

I see that the frontend is able to query DDB only once. When it tries to "poll", it throws a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function` 400 exception.
What am I doing wrong? Can I implement polling this way or is there a better way to do this?

I'm new to React and building WebApplications so I'm following a few blogs I read to perform polling. Would appreciate any help I can get on understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an easy thing instead of that.

- make state variable with boolean
- create an effect that calls the api that depends on the boolean
- make use of setInterval

If you want to re-use just make a custom hook

Comment: I can try that. Do you have any examples of this that I can use as a reference? (Sorry, I'm new to React so I'm learning on the go here)

Comment: @SudhaN, Refer to https://gist.github.com/KotanaSai21/63e585284b1f5045ef2a154b76ea380f#:~:text=const%20exportId%20%3D%20data,%7D)%3B. I implemented something similar, where i need to poll for report to be available.